# RTL8723AE not connecting to Netgear WGT624 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on my computer and have been unable to connect to my wireless network on Netgear WGT624 with WPA2-PSK [AES] encryption. I have been able to connect to a neighbor's unsecured wifi, nonetheless. I have tried downloading the dropbox drivers but received errors when compiling. I am able to connect using my other devices. I have been scouring the internet trying to find a solution but have come up empty handed. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Below is some information that might be useful.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network -numeric
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091]
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros [1969]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 00:8c:fa:23:ef:eb
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:45 memory:c8500000-c853ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10EC:8723]
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 20:68:9d:e6:58:c3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=3.13.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.99.159 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c8400000-c8403fff
```

**Edit:**
The results of `sudo iwlist scan` is shown below for the network to which I am trying to connect:

```
Cell 10 - Address: 00:14:6C:25:24:5C
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"KarlMarx"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000271e2db29
                Extra: Last beacon: 56ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00084B61726C4D617278
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C183048
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32041224606C
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                   Preauthentication Supported
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F0101000EFF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD1A00037F030100000000146C25245C02146C25245C64002C010E08
```

Here are some data from the logs

```
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'KarlMarx'
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'KarlMarx' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'KarlMarx' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'KarlMarx'
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: message repeated 7 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (SSID='KarlMarx' freq=2452 MHz)
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta kernel: [ 1088.256023] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (SSID='KarlMarx' freq=2452 MHz)
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta kernel: [ 1088.270479] wlan0: send auth to 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 1/3)
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta kernel: [ 1088.272682] wlan0: authenticated
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta kernel: [ 1088.272882] rtl8723ae 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Jul  4 14:05:14 peta kernel: [ 1088.272884] rtl8723ae 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta kernel: [ 1088.274219] wlan0: associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 1/3)
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta kernel: [ 1088.378204] wlan0: associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 2/3)
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta kernel: [ 1088.482293] wlan0: associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 3/3)
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta kernel: [ 1088.586379] wlan0: association with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c timed out
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="KarlMarx" auth_failures=1 duration=10
Jul  4 14:05:15 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jul  4 14:05:25 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jul  4 14:05:25 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="KarlMarx"
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (SSID='KarlMarx' freq=2452 MHz)
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.537265] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.552096] wlan0: send auth to 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 1/3)
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (SSID='KarlMarx' freq=2452 MHz)
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.564258] wlan0: authenticated
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.564407] rtl8723ae 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.564410] rtl8723ae 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.567680] wlan0: associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 1/3)
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.671815] wlan0: associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 2/3)
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.775903] wlan0: associate with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c (try 3/3)
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta kernel: [ 1099.879990] wlan0: association with 00:14:6c:25:24:5c timed out
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="KarlMarx" auth_failures=2 duration=20
Jul  4 14:05:26 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jul  4 14:05:36 peta wpa_supplicant[1138]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Jul  4 14:05:36 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  4 14:05:39 peta NetworkManager[952]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
Jul  4 14:05:39 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul  4 14:05:39 peta NetworkManager[952]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
Jul  4 14:05:39 peta NetworkManager[952]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jul  4 14:05:39 peta NetworkManager[952]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jul  4 14:05:42 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <warn> No agents were available for this request.
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> Marking connection 'KarlMarx' invalid.
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'KarlMarx'
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul  4 14:05:44 peta NetworkManager[952]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
```

Comment: your drivers look good, what do you mean by not connecting, it cannot find connection or cannot detect a device??

Comment: It detects the network and asks for the password, but never actually connects. The wireless icon keeps blinking as it attempts to connect. I removed the password and still got the same results.

Comment: Do you have any other os and with that os can you connect?

Comment: Yes. I have Windows 8 on the same computer and I am able to connect just fine. I also have Lubuntu running in a virtualbox inside Windows, which also works fine.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, this is my second attempt.

Comment: Your chip is supported by 14.04 out of the  box. What  channels/strengths do you see "sudo iwlist scan"  and see if you have other  strong  signals on the channel you are using. What encryption are you trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to use WPA2-PSK [AES] encryption, I have pasted the results above. There are other signals on that channel but mine is the strongest (more positive), I believe.

Comment: Your signal is good, you  authenticte, but fail to associate -- Do you perhaps have MAC filtering turned on at your AP, or maybe a  too small limit on  the number of DHCP addresses the ap passes out?  Odd  the MAC addresses from lshw differs from the log, but those numnbers may be something else.

Comment: There are no such restrictions on the AP. I ran lshw while connected to a neighbor's wifi, and the logs are from when I was trying to connect to my network, that might explain the different MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange but I finally got it to work.

First I uninstalled NetworkManager

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Then I installed wicd, which was able to connect to my network

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the common Wifi driver packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: I tried that but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. install wicd-gtk and then

`sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk`

2. uninstall network-manager

`sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager`

My laptop Acer Aspire E1-572 had no problems to connect to my netgear wireless router WGT624v3 with Ubuntu 13.10, but since update to Ubuntu 14.04 it didn't work anymore. As all other devices still were able to connect and connections from my laptop to other WiFi networks are working fine the problem seems to arise from the combination of the new network-manager with at least this type of netgear router.
I reversed Peta Paka answer to insure that network connectivity was maintainable throughout the process.

Comment: What does it adds to the already existing answer?